# jQuery function format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am taking on a project with a ton of jQuery functions and of course it is a bit confusing to me at the moment. It seems like, if the functions were broken down into javascript functions then called with jQuery, the code might be more readable. What are the advantages to doing this and why might I not do this?

For instance, right now there might be a function like this:

```
$(document).on('click', function(){
    var foo = 1;
    var bar = 2;
    var sum = foo + bar;
    console.log(sum);
});
```

But to me it seems like it'd be easier if it were like this:

```
function addStuff(){
    var foo = 1;
    var bar = 2;
    var sum = foo + bar;
    console.log(sum);
}

$(document).on('click', function(){
    addStuff();
});
```

I feel like this would make it more readable but I'm not sure if this is good convention, bad convention, or just developer's choice.

Comment: Not really more readable, but definitely more reusable and probably better practice for that reason.

Comment: Even better is `$(document).on('click', addStuff);` But the opinion of "easier", "better", and/or "more readable" is subjective to the individual person.

Comment: I'd say depends on the purpose. If you're going to reuse the code within the jQuery callbacks, the yank them out. If not, then either/or

Comment: Why is the question on hold, I wanted to give the answer on the differences in the approaches

Comment: I tried to edit it to make it acceptable but I'm not sure how to rephrase it aside from how I have it now, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends largely on reusability.  If a function is only going to be called from one specific place and nothing else ever needs it, it would make sense to have it in an anonymous function (like your first example).  If you're needing that code multiple times, it's a good idea to not repeat yourself and to have it in a named function (like your second example).

Answer (score 0):

It is OK, and depends only if you intend to reuse that function somewhere else.